# Perform specific action when any cell of TableLayoutManager clicked

Tags: blackberry, cell, tablelayout

I'm new to Blackberry development. Currently, i have an instance of TableLayoutManager to add into the UI screen. How i perform a specific action when any cell of the table is selected/clicked, as the method setOnItemClick() i used in Android?

This is my code

```
TableLayoutManager colFMgr = new TableLayoutManager(new int[] {
TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_SIZE,
TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_SIZE }, new int[] {
TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_WIDTH_WITH_MAXIMUM,
TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_WIDTH_WITH_MAXIMUM }, 5,
Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL);
for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    colFMgr.add(new BitmapField(images[i], Field.FOCUSABLE));
}
add(colFMgr);
```

TableLayoutManager is a class as defined [here](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800508/How_To_-_Create_a_rich_UI_layout_with_TableLayoutManager.html?nodeid=1906675&vernum=0)

I want to do specific action (like navigating to other screen) when any cell of the table clicked and get information about which cell is clicked.

Thank you...

Comment: you using listfield ot table ?

Comment: protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return true;
        }

Comment: also check the getFieldWithFocusIndex()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt tried this answer. Lets check it.

```
TableLayoutManager colFMgr = new TableLayoutManager(new int[] {
TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_SIZE,
TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_SIZE }, new int[] {
TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_WIDTH_WITH_MAXIMUM,
TableLayoutManager.USE_PREFERRED_WIDTH_WITH_MAXIMUM }, 5,
Manager.HORIZONTAL_SCROLL){
    protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) { 
        int k=getFieldWithFocusIndex(); 
            if(k==0){
                //clicked first row
            }else if(k==1){
                //clicked second row
            }//and so on......
        return true; 
       } 

    };

for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    colFMgr.add(new BitmapField(images[i], Field.FOCUSABLE));
    }
add(colFMgr);
```